# Many to zero relationship with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-relationship

I have difficulty understand how I can make a "connecting" table between TimeLogEntity and TimeLogPeriodEntity (see classes below).

```
public class TimeLogEntity
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }
   ...
   public TimeLogPeriodEntity TimeLogPeriod { get; set; }
}

public class TimeLogPeriodEntity
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set; }
   public DateTime From {get; set; }
   public DateTime To {get; set; }
   ...
   public ICollection<TimeLogEntity> TimeLogs{ get; set; }
}
```

I want EF to generate 3 tables: TimeLogs, TimeLogPeriods and TimeLogPeriodCrossTimeLogs,

I want a TimeLogPeriod to have multiple TimeLogs. But a TimeLog don't have to have a TimeLogPeriod.

Comment: Why 3 tables? What you are explaining sounds like standard 2 table one-to-many [optional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#required-and-optional-relationships) relationship - i.e. `TimeLogEntity.TimeLogPeriod` property and associated FK being nullable.

Comment: @IvanStoev I could add TimeLogId to TimeLogPeriodEntity, but then I would have to repeat the Period name for each row.

Comment: It is other way around. `int? TimeLogPeriodId` in `TimeLogEntity`. Basically what you'll get from the shown model classes by default.

Comment: @IvanStoev Could work, but most of the TimeLogEntities have no TimeLogPeriod, so it would be alot of null values.

Comment: That's true. But that's the only working design with EF Core (up to including latest at this time EFC v6.0) since it supports the so called skip navigations and implicit join entity only for many-to-many relationships. In order to get 3 tables, you have to create 3 entities - the 2 in question + 1 explicit join entity, and define 2 relationships - 1 one-to-one and 1 one-to-many. And navigation properties referencing the join entity rather than the other entity.